# How to solve distorted image issue in android custom camera for galaxy S4

Tags: android

I am working on custom camera application for android. The problem is that the camera capture and showing preview good in other devices (example Samsung Galaxy S3) , but It shows distorted 
image on Galaxy s4, Can any one help me??

My code for Picturesize() method is as follows:

```
Camera.Size getBestPicturSize(int width, int height, Camera.Parameters parameters) {
        Camera.Size result=null;
        float dr = Float.MAX_VALUE;
        float ratio = (float)width/(float)height;

        for (Camera.Size size : parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes()) {
            float r = (float)size.width/(float)size.height;
            if( Math.abs(r - ratio) < dr && size.width <= width && size.height <= height ) {
                dr = Math.abs(r - ratio);
                result = size;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps show some screen-shots of how it looks distorted.

Comment: I am unable to post screen shot as I am new on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, if you mean that photos were taken with aspect ratio 4:3 and saved with aspect ratio 16:9 (they were outstretched). My problem was, that since I chose one of supported **PictureSizes**, I didn't do the same with the **PreviewSizes**.
Supported **PictureSizes** for Samsung G S4 are only with aspect ratio 16:9, however default **PreviewSize** was set to 1440x1080, which is 4:3. When I set both sizes with the **same** aspect ratio, picture was taken with no distortion.

Hope it will help.